# Wait and signal mechanism for kext development macOS

Tags: macos, synchronization, kernel-extension

I am developing a macOS kernel extension. Currently in need of wait and signal mechanism for the kext development. Similar to struct completion  on Linux OS. I tried using semaphore for macOS. However, facing some difficulties as semaphore create is causing a kernel panic. Please suggest some alternate mechanisms. With sample code would be great.

I have posted a different question about why semaphore create is failing. [Semaphore_create causes kernel panic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55627841/semaphore-create-causes-kernel-panic)

Please suggest some alternatives or sample code which I can refer to create the wait and signal mechanism for kext development.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer I provided to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20750632/48660)? Does that help? If not, what's missing?

Comment: @pmdj Thank you for the response. This link points to IOKit. I am developing Generic kext. Have implemented a wait on the similar lines.

Comment: void* CreateAndInitializeEvent()
{
    
    int * volatile lock = _MALLOC(sizeof(int));
    *lock = 0;
    return lock;
}
void WaitOnEvent(void* p_event)
{
    int * volatile lock = (int * volatile) p_event;
    //waittime == 1ms
    //Every time it fails sleep for a while
    while (!OSCompareAndSwap(1, 0, lock)){
        msleep(p_event, NULL, 0, "", &waittime);
    }
}
void SetEvent(void* p_event)
{
    volatile int * lock = (volatile int *) p_event;
    *lock = 1;
    wakeup_one(p_event);
}

Comment: That looks inefficient/unreliable. The IOLocks just wrap the implementations in [`<kern/locks.h>`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1228.5.18/osfmk/kern/locks.h.auto.html). (`lck_mtx_…`) For everyone’s sake, I recommend you use those if you don’t want to link against the IOKit KPI.

Comment: Inefficient: I agree, looping because of small sleep period. Not sure why it is unreliable. Also, asking as a rookie curios programmer who wants to learn, what have I missed why is it unreliable ? 
The use case I am having is simple. There are 2 tasks, just want to be sure that task A gets executed before task B. Hence In task B I wait on Signal and at the end of task A, the event is signalled.

Comment: For example, if `SetEvent()` is called more than once, only one waiting thread will wake up, not 2. `*lock = 1;` also has no particular memory coherence guarantees, which could bite you in certain tight timing scenarios. (Apple recently got this wrong when they made changes to `IOSharedDataQueue` in macOS 10.13.6 and   introduced a deadlock regression.)

Comment: *lock = 1; also has no particular memory coherence guarantees: Agreed thought of using test and set. @pmdj thank you